# What should I do if the error message “unknow:26000” is displayed when GSQL is used to connect to the database?

Tags: open-gauss

What should I do if the error message “unknow:26000” is displayed when GSQL is used to connect to the database?
gsql -d postgres =p 26000 -r
failed to connect Unkown:26000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello I am beginner in open gauss database but I have observed  a syntaxical error in your query  I think it must be like this :

```
gsql -d postgres -p 8000 -r
```

(- instead of = and the port number 8000 instead of 26 000)
hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if port 26000 exists, confirm if the port and service of openGauss are started.